# Function returns other recursive function in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Suppose we have a function f. This function takes as an argument a list l and returns a function of one argument g.Function g takes as an argument x and looking for the x in the list l. If it finds it returns true, else false.

I'm interested in a solution without using the built-in functions. 
My start code:

```
(define (f l) 
(lamda (x) 
.......... 
)))
```

Comment: Which are the functions you'd like to avoid?

Comment: Solve it using builtin functions, then replace the builtins with your own implementations of them. Don't do both things at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for this:

```
(define (f l)
  (lambda (x)
    (and (member x l) #t)))

(define g (f '(a b c e)))
(g 'a)
=> #t
(g 'd)
=> #f
```

If you need to avoid the built-in `member` procedure, you can roll your own `member?`:

```
(define (member? e l)
  (and (not (null? l))
       (or (eq? (car l) e) (member? e (cdr l)))))

(define (f l)
  (lambda (x)
    (member? x l)))
```

or have `member?` as an internal procedure, if you prefer:

```
(define (f l)
  (define (member? e l)
    (and (not (null? l))
         (or (eq? (car l) e) (member? e (cdr l)))))
  (lambda (x)
    (member? x l)))
```